# SQLCE Subquery for smart device application

Tags: c#

I create two tables name abc1 and xyz.

abc1 having column id, name and add. where xyz table having id, mob.

```
select name from abc1 where id =(select id from xyz)
```

getting an error

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 34,Token in error = select ]

please help me on this query.

Answer (score 0):

select name from abc1 where id IN (select id from xyz) // because select id from xyz can return lots of rows

or

```
select name from abc1 where id =(select id from xyz where mob=...) // for only one result
```